# Phaser3, trying to use svg emoji as cursor

Tags: css, svg, phaser-framework

given the [docs](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/cursor/#set-cursor-of-a-game-object), the following should work but doesn't give me any inclination as to why it's not.

```
this.input.setDefaultCursor(`url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'  width='48' height='58' viewport='0 0 100 100' style='fill:black;font-size:29px;'><text y='50%'>⬇</text></svg>") 16 0,auto`)
```

the emoji cursor was generated here: https://www.emojicursor.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. After a closer look, i was actually also setting the cursor elsewhere as something else that was overwriting this. Either way, I will leave the question open in case someone wants to know how to use emoji as cursors in phaser3